# Select optional nodes with XPath

Tags: html, xpath-1.0

I have an HTML fragment:

```
<td>
   <span class="x-cell">something</span>
   <span class="y-cell">something</span>
   <span class="z-cell">something</span>
   A text
   <span class="foo"/>
   Another text
   <span class="bar"/>
   Also text
</td>
```

I try to select all nodes following the `<span class="z-cell"/>` to move them into another node. But all the nodes within `td` are optional, I can have zero to three `<span class="*-cell"/>`, the text is optional and there could be further `<span>` nodes in the middle/begin/end of the text or not.

In short, I have to move all nodes except the `<span class="*-cell"/>` into another node. I tried XPath to select the nodes:

`td/span[contains(@class,"-cell")][last()]/following-sibling::*`

but it doesn't work, if there aren't any `<span class="*-cell"/>` nodes. How I could solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Have your xpath expression exclude all elements you do not want:

```
td/(*[not(contains(@class,"-cell"))]|text())
```

If you only want to copy elements without the intervening text this simplifies to

```
td/*[not(contains(@class,"-cell"))]
```

Live Demo on [XPathTester](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/e2159d285d1a5e6c10502ef54958fdad)